# How to disable Feed Based page layout on Accounts

Tags: page-layout, person-accounts

For the person account layout in my org, the feed based layout is enabled.
I want to disable it and revert to the standard layout which we were using before.
Any idea how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can't convert a feed-based layout to a standard one, but you can copy the feed-based one and not check the feed-based box when you create a new one. Once you have a non-feed based layout, then just assign the new layout to the desired record types and profiles.